# Expensive column causes slow query with large offset

Tags: postgresql, performance

I am attempting to do a query that retrieves an expensive column on a table with a large offset. However, as the offset gets larger the query goes slower and slower until it does not resolve in a reasonable time.

The part I am confused about is that the expensive part of the query is within the `SELECT` part of the statement. I would have thought this would have little bearing on the final timing.

Each individual part of the query is fast:

```
SELECT expensive_column FROM table WHERE id='1234567'
```

```
SELECT id FROM table OFFSET 1234567 LIMIT 1
```

However, when doing them in a single query there are massive performance impacts:

```
SELECT expensive_column FROM table OFFSET 1234567 LIMIT 1
```

I can however re-write the query to be fast by doing:

```
SELECT expensive_column FROM table WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM expensive_table OFFSET 1234567 LIMIT 1
)
```

I was wondering if anyone could explain why an expensive column would effect a query in this way?

Comment: The first two queries are doing completely different things. An `offset` without an `ORDER BY` will most likely **not** return the row with id = 1234567.

Comment: You first look for correctness, then efficiency.

Comment: What does it mean for a column to be expensive?

Comment: Providing the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to your queries would help with performance advice, but yes as the other comments mentioned, your queries are probably logically incorrect anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `id` is a primary serial key, and therefore indexed by b-tree, the separate queries use the index for the query, while the combined query doesn't. I am not sure if it's your mistake, but the combined query will return a different value each call without `ORDER BY` clause, so that means the query planner has to scan table for different sequences of `1234567` rows to find the last item.
The last query again uses an index for finding the row and therefore is as fast as the first ones.